# How do I write a Google app for OpenID Connect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-openid

I have created a Google open ID spring boot app following the instructions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect). I run this with the link:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=its asecret&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/google-login&state=abc`

I then allow the app to have off-line access and get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a ...    
Mon Dec 31 12:31:51 GMT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=None, status=999).
```

Now I expect this could be because my app doen't really do anything. I have set its 'Authorized redirect URIs' to http://localhost:8081/google-login.

I cannot find anything that gives an example of how to create such an app. Everything I have found seems to be about *connecting to* such an app.

Can anyone give me an example? (I just want the app to handle OPEN ID connect access so just a dummy app).

OR perhaps this is enough and I have another problem?
TIA!